# How To Save Chat in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hi All i am working on a windows phone chat application and i have done chatting with both end now i am facing issue when i reopen my app my all previous chat history is removed. how i can save my previous chat history please help me.
Thanks

i am using following code

```
  <ListBox Name="listChat"  Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Instance.Messages,Source={StaticResource Binder}}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="430">
                                    <cc:ChatBubble Width="380" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MType},ConverterParameter=align}"   Opacity="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MType}}" ChatBubbleDirection="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MType},ConverterParameter=direction}" Margin="0,0,0,10"  >
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontSize="17" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="17" Text="{Binding SendingDate}"></TextBlock>

                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="txt_Msg" Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="430"></TextBlock>


                                        </Grid>
                                    </cc:ChatBubble>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Dumping random code from your project that has absolutely nothing to do with your question isn't productive.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is Isolated Storage

For example I have this helper class

```
public static class SettingsManager
{
    private static IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings;

    public static IsolatedStorageSettings AppSettings
    {
        get { return SettingsManager.appSettings; }
        set { SettingsManager.appSettings = value; }
    }

    public static void LoadSettings()
    {
        if (appSettings == null)
            appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        if (!appSettings.Contains(SettingValues.LoadedData))
            appSettings[SettingValues.LoadedData] = false;

        appSettings.Save();
    }

    public static void SaveValue(string key, object value)
    {
        appSettings[key] = value;
        appSettings.Save();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows

```
SettingsManager.SaveValue("myname", someVariableYouWantToStore);
```

And after start, you can load it with

```
SettingsManager.AppSettings["myname"]
```